# The difference between the free $A$-module $A^{(M\times N)}$, and $M\times N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ and $N$ be two $A$-modules, where $A$ is a commutative ring. What is the difference between the free $A$-module $A^{(M\times N)}$, and $M\times N$?

In Atiyah-Macdonald, both of these seem to have the same description. Hence the confusion.

Comment: They're different. $M \times N$ isn't necessarily free. Try some simple examples like $A = \mathbb Z$, $M = N = \mathbb Z/(2)$. Then $M \times N = \mathbb Z/(2) \times \mathbb Z / (2)$, whereas $A^{(M \times N)}$ is the free $\mathbb Z$-module generated by $4$ elements.

Comment: You don't mean $A^{M \times N}$. You mean $A^{|M| \times |N|}$, where $|M|$ denotes the underlying set of $M$. There is a fundamental difference between $M$ and $|M|$ (which is unfortunately ignored by many people and also enforced by the usual abuse of notation). In particular, $A^{|M| \times |N|}$ doesn't "know" anything(!) about the module structure $M$ - just the underlying set $|M|$ of it.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Unfortunately, $A^{(M \times N)}$ is the notation used in AM. The book does explain the meaning behind the notation, but perhaps it's not very clear if one isn't already comfortable with free modules.

Answer (score 2):

When you write $A^{(M \times N)}$ you're denoting a free $A$-module with basis indexed by $M \times N$.  In general, you can expect this to be much bigger than $M \times N$.

For instance, if we consider the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $M = 2 \mathbb{Z}$, then $\mathbb{Z}^{(M)}$ is the free module indexed by the set $\{0, \pm 2, \pm 4, \dots\}$, i.e.,
$$ \mathbb{Z}^{(M)} = \mathbb{Z}_0 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{-2} \oplus \dots $$

This is horrible notation that just means that I get a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ for every element in my **index set** $M$.  So the important point is that in this example, I not thinking of $M$ as a module at all.  It's **just a set** over which I perform the sum.  Another notation could be
$$ \mathbb{Z}^{(M)} = \bigoplus_{\alpha \in M} \mathbb{Z}_\alpha $$
where $\mathbb{Z}_\alpha$ just means "the copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ corresponding to $\alpha$."

Here is @Ayman's example worked out:  If $M = \mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$ is the abelian group with two elements, then $M \times M$ is the abelian group ($\mathbb{Z}$-module) $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, which is a finite group ($\mathbb{Z}$-module) with four elments, say $a,b,c,d$.  Then 
$$\mathbb{Z}^{M \times M} = \bigoplus_{\alpha \in M\times M} \mathbb{Z}_\alpha = 
\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$$

... much bigger than $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$!

**EDIT:**  I just looked at Atiyah-MacDonald (p.21 in my copy) and I think maybe the confusion is that they denoted a free $A$-module over a set $I$ by $A^{(I)}$?  To be clear, they never mean for $I$ to be an ideal or module of $A$.  It's just a set, like maybe $I = \{2,3,5\}$ so $A^{(I)}$ would be $A \oplus A \oplus A$.

Comment: Does addition and scalar multiplication still take place component-wise? Is one major difference the fact that sums of infinite number of terms of $M\times N$ is allowed in $A^{(M\times N)}$ while it is not in $M\times N$?

Comment: @AyushKhaitan As Martin says, you need to forget everything about the algebraic structure of $M\times N$: when we make the free $A$-module out of it, to us it's just a set like any other. That is why I spoke of $A^X$ for an arbitrary set $X$ in my answer.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan I've edited my answer to add Ayman's example

Answer (score 0):

What is the difference between $X$ and $A^X$ in general? Well, are $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\Bbb R^3$ any different? A more revealing rhetorical question: are $\{\vec{i},\vec{j},\vec{k}\}$ and $\Bbb R^3$ any different? Obviously, but the first spans the second: everything in the space is a unique $\Bbb R$-linear combination of things in the set. This is exactly how it works with free modules on a set: everything in $A^X$ is an $A$-linear combination of $X$'s things.